# ALU carry in/out

Tags: cpu, alu

Say there is an ALU with 3 inputs (A, B, Cin) and 2 outputs (Res, Cout).

It has functions [A plus B, A minus B, B minus A, A or B, 0, 1].

From my understanding, this is how the carry-in/out work for addition.

```
A   B   Cin     Cout    Res
0   0   0       0       0
1   0   0       0       1
0   1   0       0       1
1   1   0       1       0
0   0   1       0       1
1   0   1       1       0
0   1   1       1       0
1   1   1       1       1
```

What about for the other functions? How are the carry-in/out used, or does the carry-out just output 0?

Comment: You may find answers here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_flag

Comment: The carry value depends on the exact ALU logic used for subtraction. However, it's not uncommon to use XOR gates to invert one of the input sources and to supply CIN=1 during a subtraction without borrow, while using the exact same adder to perform the subtraction. So, for a 1-bit adder just keep the same adder (no changes to it) but now take the subtrahend input and invert it's bit in your table and then also set the carry-in to "1" when there is no "borrow" and to "0" when there is a "borrow." See what results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADD:

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
A & B &  Cin &    Cout &   Res\\\\
0 & 0 & 0    &   0  &     0\\
1 &  0 &  0   &    0    &   1\\
0 &  1 &  0   &    0    &   1\\
1 &  1 &  0   &    1    &   0\\\\
0 &  0 &  1    &   0    &   1\\
1 &  0 &  1    &   1    &   0\\
0 &  1 &  1    &   1    &   0\\
1 &  1 &  1    &   1    &   1 
\end{array}$$

You already understand the above table, I gather. So no further explanation needed.

Look at SUB, though. With subtraction, it is often the case that something akin to using an XOR takes place to invert the subtrahend's bits. So a "subtract" control signal is applied to one side of the XOR (or all of them, if there is a lot of bits in \$B\$), with this control signal being a "1". Then \$B\$ is applied to the other XOR input. The output of the XOR is fed to the adder, in the usual fashion as a newly inverted addend. To make this all work right, the carry-in also is inverted ("1" if no borrow and "0" if there is a borrow.)

Note below that I've inverted \$B\$ and that now "no borrow" means that \$C_{in}=1\$. So the first four rows are for "no borrow" and the last four rows are for "with borrow":

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
A & B &  Cin &    Cout &   Res\\\\
0 & 1 & 1    &   1  &     0\\
1 &  1 &  1   &    1    &   1\\
0 &  0 &  1   &    0    &   1\\
1 &  0 &  1   &    1    &   0\\\\
0 &  1 &  0    &   0    &   1\\
1 &  1 &  0    &   1    &   0\\
0 &  0 &  0    &   0    &   0\\
1 &  0 &  0    &   0    &   1 
\end{array}$$

To interpret the above, note that if you see a "1" under the \$B\$ column, this just meant that \$B=0\$ and that the XOR gate inverted it for the subtraction operation prior to the bit value reaching the ALU's adder section. Also, if you see \$C_{in}=0\$ here, this means that there was a borrow that must ***also*** be subtracted before generating a result. Finally, if \$C_{out}=1\$ then this means there is no further borrow from the next stage. But if \$C_{out}=0\$ then this means a borrow is required from the next stage.

---

Not every ALU uses the above subtraction method. I've seen cases where if the carry in is 0 it means no borrow. But in my opinion that's usually when some ALU designer is misguided enough to try bending over backwards to add wasted logic just to please future silly programmers expected to complain about it.

Answer (score 1):

Carry is only applicable to the arithmetic part of your Arithmetic/Logic Unit. For logic and constant functions, it would output logic 0 as you suspected.

Comment: What about for subtraction?

Comment: The principle arithmetic functions are addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. As carry applies to arithmetic functions, it therefore applies to your addition and subtraction.